# Shouldn't Java forbid the use of abstract methods in constructors?

Tags: java, oop

I just came across a subtle trap. Consider the next two classes:

```
/**
 * Innocent-looking example that causes trouble. See {@link B}.
 *
 */
public abstract class A  {

    abstract String someStringLeftForExtensionsToSpecify();

    public A() {
        super();
        processString(someStringLeftForExtensionsToSpecify());
    }

    void processString(String string) {
        // do complicated things with string that are shared by all extensions
        // so this could should be here.
    }
}

/**
 * Looks innocent enough, but abstract method is used in {@link A}'s constructor before
 * property is set, even though it uses property.
 */
public class B extends A {

    private int property;

    public B(int property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

    public String someStringLeftForExtensionsToSpecify() {
        if (property == 13) {
            return "Unlucky";
        }
        return "Lucky";
    }
}
```

It seems that using an abstract method inside a constructor should be a no-no in OOP. Shouldn't Java forbid this, in the same way it forbids the use of "this" or non-static methods as arguments to "super"? I wonder if this is a well-known thing.

Comment: You are confused about what an actual runtime instance of `A` **is**. At runtime, it must be a concrete type that implements the specified method. That is what an `abstract` type is.

Comment: You're right that this is a potential trap. It's even more general: any non-final method is succeptible. I don't know why they don't disallow it; probably just for simplicity of the language, but that's just a guess.

Comment: I know I get a warning about it with NetBeans IDE.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, I am not confused, I know what abstract types are, and I understand why this is incorrect. The question is about whether Java should forbid it (this compiles fine in Eclipse).

Comment: All computer languages make decisions about syntax and semantics. Questions like "Shouldn't this language do X?" are cute, but usually better for musings over beers than JCP submissions. There are a few rare use cases where you want polymorphism in the constructor. And it'd've been hard to anticipate what people would need, or how to prevent people from hanging themselves when you give'em enough rope. Are you quite sure your idea won't have unintended bad consequences? Have you really thought it all through? Have you mastered Java as it is today to judge what it lacks for real?

Comment: @user118967 *ClasseDefiningAbstractMethodUsedInItsSupersConstructorThatUsesPropertySetInItsOwnConstructor*.. What is that thing? It doesn't even have a return type. Your constructors need to have the same name as the class. Even if this is pseudo code, let's not abuse the language syntax to this extent.

Comment: @CKing thanks for catching the problem. That's B's constructor. I wrote it in Eclipse but when here decided to rename the classes with shorter names, but forgot to rename the constructor. Fixed now.

Comment: @LewBloch, I am not judging, I am trying to learn more and perhaps contribute to the general understanding of Java by the community. I know polymorphism is not allowed in arguments to super, and this seems an almost identical situation to me that, as my example shows, can trick the programmer, so I am trying to see if there are legitimate needs for it, or if it would be better forbidden but for whatever reason is not.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that using an abstract method inside a constructor should be
>   a no-no in OOP. Shouldn't Java forbid this, in the same way it forbids
>   the use of "this" or non-static methods as arguments to "super"? I
>   wonder if this is a well-known thing.

and

> The question is about whether Java should forbid it (this compiles
>   fine in Eclipse)

The reason that `this` is problematic as an argument to a client method is that there is a significant risk of the client receiving a reference to an object that has not been completely constructed, i.e. when it is in an inconsistent state and/or its invariants are not intact.  The compiler is warning about `this` being in an invalid state.

But who says that the invocation of a non-final method from within a constructor is dangerous?  If you're not passing `this` to the method, then it isn't receiving a reference to an object in an invalid state.

Could this be dangerous?  It depends.  If references to mutable or secure objects could be intercepted by malicious clients, then certainly.  But this has to do with security considerations in the design of the whole application, not simply the constructor.

In some contexts, it may even be desirable for a constructor to invoke an overrideable, non-final method ... because polymorphism is not a no-no in object oriented programming.

The real issue that you're addressing is accessibility.  The engineer must not export into the API any methods (both final or non-final) that he doesn't want a client to have access to.